# Insignificant predictors and significant F stat

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

The F stat for my model is very high (F= 3128851.522, p=.000), but only four of my predictors are significant out of a total of nine predictors. The no. of observations is 20. What should i do?

Comment: Maybe do forward selection or backward elimination of predictor variables to get rid of some inconsequential predictors.

Comment: This may happen, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151403/significance-of-individual-coefficients-vs-significance-of-both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either gather a lot more data or formulate different research questions.

Having 9 predictors with 20 observations is going to overfit your model dramatically. A general rule of thumb is that you need 10 observations for each independent variable.